# Java: Drop to next `catch` clause

Tags: java, exception

I have the following structure:

```
try {
  Request.Get(url).execute() // Apache Fluent
  // do some other stuff
} catch (HttpResponseException e) {
  if (e.getStatusCode() != 404) {
    //drop to next catch clause
  }
  handle404(e);
} catch (IOException e) {
  handleGenericIOException(e);
}
```

I can't figure out what goes in that `if` statement. I want to just say "if the exception isn't a 404, act like this clause never caught it".  But simply calling `throw e` just throws it out from the method.  Is there a way to pass forward to the next `catch` clause?

Comment: *Is there a way to pass forward to the next catch clause?* There is not. But you could add a `handleGenericIOException(e);` in your `if` block (and then `return`).

Comment: Or you could use `@ExceptionHandler`. In that case, inside the handler you could have your if-case, which would re-throw the correct exception, which would be picked up by the correct exception handler.

Comment: @SofoGial can you post an answer with an example of how this would work? This sounds like what I want but I've never heard of `@ExceptionHandler` before

Comment: For my 2 cents, I think you should handle the non-404 HTTPResponseExceptions differently than in IOException. Better to differentiate between network issues and a response code being sent back that indicates a problem

Answer (score 4):

Nest your exception handlers.

```
try {
  try {
    Request.Get(url).execute() // Apache Fluent
    // do some other stuff
  } catch (HttpResponseException e) {
    if (e.getStatusCode() != 404) {
      throw e;
    }
    handle404(e);
  }
} catch (IOException e) {
  handleGenericIOException(e);
}
```

The re-throw will be caught in the outer try / catch block because `HttpResponseException` is a sub-class of `IOException`.

Answer (score 2):

I don't think you can "drop" to the next catch clause, but you could probably do something like this:

```
try {
  Request.Get(url).execute() // Apache Fluent
  // do some other stuff
} catch (IOException e) {
  if (e instanceof HttpResponseException
      && ((HttpResponseException)e).getStatusCode()== 404) {
    handle404(e);
  } else {
    handleGenericIOException(e);
  }
}
```

since IOException should also catch HttpResponseExceptions (if it's a `org.apache.http.client.HttpResponseException`)